# Access model method from rabl template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I'm trying to access a model method in a Ruby on Rails rabl template but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass in an argument to the function. Here's the model code -

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: User
    belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: User

  def opposed_user(user)
    user == recipient ? sender : recipient
  end

end
```

And here's my rabl template file -

```
collection @conversations, object_root: false
attributes :id, :sender_id, :recipient_id

node :otheruser do |c|
    c.opposed_user(current_user)
end
```

Specifically it's the `opposed_user` that I'm trying to return but the error I'm getting with the above is `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. `current_user` is returning the correct user ok so is this is simple thing or am I going about it in the wrong way?

**Update**

If I use `c.opposed_user(current_user).to_json` it works however the json is returning an escaped string rather than the actual json object. I think maybe I need to use child instead of node but not sure.

Comment: That should be in your user model so that you call `current_user.opposed_user`

Comment: But then I wouldn't have access to the `sender` and `recipient` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you were fairly close to solving this. You can use `as_json` instead of `to_json` to fix the RABL template you already have.

The final template would look like this:

```
collection @conversations, object_root: false
attributes :id, :sender_id, :recipient_id

node :otheruser do |c|
  c.opposed_user(current_user).as_json
end
```

With RABL, there are a number of different ways to handle things. When you use `node`, it will simply add one key if you provide a string. Since `to_json` returns a string, you end up with something like `{ otheruser: "whatever string you provided" }`.

However, if you use `as_json`, you'll end up providing a hash which `node` can also handle. For example, like this:

```
node :otheruser do |c|
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' }
end
```

You'll end up with JSON that looks like: `{ otheruser: { id: 1, name: 'Bob' } }`. Here's a [link to the documentation on node in RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#partials).